# Best Practice: DB with tables of same structure

Tags: sql, datanucleus

I have three classes with the same content(-structure).
They will be persisted in a DB (with datanucleus).

My Ideas:

**1. Version:** One table with an extra column for the Type (A,B or C).

**2. Version:** Three tables with same structure (one for each Class).

The Objects of the Classes A,B and C will be stored (in the programm) in three seperate Lists.

Is it better to accept the redundency or `SELECT ... WHERE type = ?` on every fetch?

Comment: make another table for classes and reference them with class_id column in the table. Learn more about normalization

Comment: I thought about that, but i haven't figured out yet how to do it with datanucleus - may be with inheritance